# summarize int of Dictionary<string, LikesDistribution>

Tags: c#

I have the next data:

for each post I have id-s that likes the post.

for example:

```
post: "Hi"
"12345"
"11111"
"22222"
"33333"

post: "bye"
"16666"
"77777"
"12345"
"33333"
```

etc

I defined the next variables:

```
Dictionary<string, LikesDistribution> IdsToLikesDistribution;
```

and the `class`:

```
public class LikesDistribution {
    public int counter;
    public List<string> posts;
}
```

I want to count the total likes and the posts that each of the user likes.

for the above example:

```
"12345" 2 "Hi" "Bye"
"11111" 1 "Hi"
"22222" 1 "Hi"
"33333" 2 "Hi" "Bye"
"16666" 1 "Bye"
"77777" 1 "Bye"
```

if my dictionary was from Id to number of likes:

```
Dictionary<string, int> IdsToLikesDistribution;
```

I could do something like:

```
int value;
// if it doesn't exist
if (!IdsToLikesDistribution.TryGetValue(fanId, out value))
{
    IdsToLikesDistribution.Add(fanId, 1);
}
// it exists so increase it by 1
else
{
    IdsToLikesDistribution[fanId] = value + 1;
}
```

but now I don't know how to do it.

any help appreciated!

Comment: Not sure I totally understand . . . what are the keys of your dictionary? And what is "counter"? Show me how you would access, for example, "12345".

Comment: Oh, nevermind. I think I see. You have SEPARATE objects for the data you provided and you want to put it into a dictionary. Got it.

Comment: the keys are the ids ("12345", "11111", etc). the counter counts the total likes of all of the post. for example: user: "12345" likes two posts: "Hi" and "Bye". so the counter is 2 and the posts are: "Hi" and "Bye". I hope I explain better. thank you..

Comment: How is the initial data stored? Do you have an array of ids?

Comment: In other words, where are you getting "Hi" and the corresponding list of ids? It's impossible to formulate a helpful answer if we don't know the starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what you want to know is how to set/read Class attributes.

From my understanding of your explanation, `IdsToLikesDistribution[fanId]` returns an instance of the Class `LikesDistribution`.

If that's the case, you can just call `IdsToLikesDistribution[fanId].counter` to get the `counter` value and work with it just the way you would when you map the Ids to the number of likes.

Likewise, `IdsToLikesDistribution[fanId].posts` will return the list of posts that the user likes, and you can append or remove new/old posts to the list.

Let me know if I can clarify further!